# show hidden div only if form is filled on submit

Tags: forms, submit, fill

It has been one week that I'm trying to achieve that, but I don't manage to make it work . . .

I've a result contain in a div, which is show when we submit a form with the information of the user.

I've "link" the result with a contact form to send all the information by email.

I'd like to show this div (of the result, which is call resultKeeper), only after the submitting is filled, as at the moment user can click submit, and the result appear immediately, even the form is not fill. . . but I receive the information by email only if they fill everything .

here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
// I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
var uname = $("input[name=senderName]").val(); 
var uemail = $("input[name=senderEmail]").val();
    var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()

$.post('submit.php',{senderName:uname,senderEmail:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
      // result variable contains your response text
      // I guess you trying to update your response 
     // notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
 $('#responseMessage').html(result);
});


  // you dont require `return false`
  // you have already did it using e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

My php submit:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['senderName'];
   $email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $results = $_POST['results'];
   $results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $message \n Results: \n      $results";
   $recipient = "email@email.com";
   $subject = "subject";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "";
   ?>
```

My html of the form:

```
   <form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="quesForm">
   <label form="senderName">Your Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required maxlength="40" /><br/>

   <label form="senderEmail">Your Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your name" required maxlength="40" /><br/>

<label form="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Your Message</label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message"  required maxlength="40" />

 <input id="button"  type="submit" value="Send" class="btnShowResult"  >
```

Thank you all your help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of things you have left out :

1. You are not returning any data from your PHP to JQUERY post
2. There's no $result in your submission, so there's no need for your php to use it
3. There's no div or other item in your html named #responseMessage, so i created one

The code below should work

```
<?php $name = $_POST['senderName'];
$email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
//$results = $_POST['results'];
//$results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message \n";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "subject";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
//mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
print $formcontent;
?>
```

//note that i commented out the mail because i have not configured smtp so i didnt want it to "die"

For your html and jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="quesForm">
<label form="senderName">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required maxlength="40" />
<br/>
<label form="senderEmail">Your Email Address</label>
<input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your name" required maxlength="40" /><br/>

<label form="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Your Message</label>
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message"  required maxlength="40" />
<input id="button"  type="submit" value="Send" class="btnShowResult"  >
<div id="responseMessage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
// I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
var uname = $("input[name=senderName]").val(); 
var uemail = $("input[name=senderEmail]").val();
var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()
$.post('submit.php', {senderName:uname,senderEmail:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
  // result variable contains your response text
// I guess you trying to update your response 
// notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
$('#responseMessage').html(result);
});
});
});
</script>
```

UPDATED JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
var jQuiz = {
    answers: { q1: 'c'},
    questionLenght: 1,
    checkAnswers: function() {
        var arr = this.answers;
        var ans = this.userAnswers;
        var resultArr = []
        for (var p in ans) {
            var x = parseInt(p) + 1;
            var key = 'q' + x;
            var flag = false;
            if (ans[p] == 'q' + x + '-' + arr[key]) {
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                flag = false;
            }
            resultArr.push(flag);
        }
        return resultArr ;
    },
    init: function(){
        $('.btnNext').click(function(){
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {

                return false;
            }
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
            });
            var el = $('#progress');
            el.width(el.width() + 300 + 'px');
        });
        $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).prev().fadeIn(500)
            });
            var el = $('#progress');
            el.width(el.width() - 300 + 'px');
        })
        $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
            var arr = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
            var ans = jQuiz.userAnswers = [];
            for (var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
                ans.push(arr[i].getAttribute('id'))
            }
        })
        $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
            $('#progress').width(300);
            $('#progressKeeper').hide();
            var results = jQuiz.checkAnswers();
            var resultSet = '';
            var trueCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++){
                if (results[i] == true) trueCount++;
                resultSet += '<div id="questionanswrs"> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] + '</div>'

            }
            resultSet += '<div class="totalScoreok"></br>Your total score is ' + trueCount * 1 + ' / 20</div>'
            //$('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show(); 

                if (trueCount > 15) {
resultSet += '<div class="totalScore"></br>results goes here</div>'
            //$('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();
                                }

                                  if (trueCount <= 15 && trueCount >10)  {
resultSet += '<div class="totalScore"></br>results goes here</div>'
            //$('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();            
                    }   

                     if (trueCount <=10 && trueCount >5)  {
resultSet += '<div class="totalScore"></br>results goes here</div>'
            //$('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();            
                    }   

                 if (trueCount <= 5) {
resultSet += '<div class="totalScore"></br>results gose here</div>'
            //$('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();
                                }
    var uname = $("input[name=senderName]").val(); 
    var uemail = $("input[name=senderEmail]").val();
    var msg = $("input[name=message]").val()
    if ((uname != null && uname!="")&& (uemail!=null && uemail!="" && uemail.indexOf("@")!=-1) && (msg !=null && msg!="")){     
            console.log("msg'" + msg + "'");
    }else{
        resultSet="Error message. Please complete your form";
    }
        $('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();              
        })
    }
};


jQuiz.init();
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I've try your code but it doesnt change anything . ..  if i click on submit without completing the form, the resuts still appear . .  .

I've put a JSfiddle with the allcode if it makes things more clear . . .

I really appreciate your time and explication, Im beginning with php , ajax and jquery so . .  thank you for =)

Here is the jsfiddle: ( the php is in the css)

http://jsfiddle.net/u4YgB/4/

Comment: I didn't realize that you wanted some validation. You want the response to show only if an empty form is submitted ??

Comment: Let me confirm if i have the correct logic :
If form is not complete, then DON'T DISPLAY ANYTHING
If form is complete, then DISPLAY AND SEND EMAIL
is this correct ?

Comment: exatcly this, yes =)

here is the link where im working on:

http://thibaultrolando.com/battersea/cr/new/la/levelA_ok.html

You can see at the moment, If you click submit without filling the form, the results appear I'd like the result to appear only if the form is submit, and send by email the result.

Really appreciate your help

Comment: I have done some little change on the fiddle to give you idea of what i think can be done. I won't have much time to debug. For instance, don't show the resultset until below where you can validate. 
Later when I have time, I can look further. But i believe you can get the idea.

Comment: Check the fiddle again.

Comment: great, it's working ! A last thing I'd like to achieve is that, when the user submit and the form is not filled to show another div (eg. please complete the form to submit"). If you give me a last help with that please =).

Thank you so much

Comment: okay. Let me look at the fiddle. You are not using "if-else" properly.

Comment: Hi, I didnt update the fiddle, I've post the last version of the code below as an answer if it can help you . . thing is that my else statment appear also when i submit the if .. .  it should not appear wat the same time, I dont know why  . .

Comment: i have modified my answer. check the section called "UPDATED JAVASCRIPT". also the fiddle works now. Kindly mark my response as answer if i've been able to help

Comment: great it work, the only thing is that now, after submitting I arrive on a blank page of the submit.php . . . . sorry to ask you so much  . .

Comment: I've update it, the thing is now, after submit, it redirect on the submit.php, all blank with the formcontent that is send to the email appearing . . . http://jsfiddle.net/u4YgB/13/

Comment: no sorry, it work perfectly =), thank you so much for all your time !!!!!!!! realyl like it !

Comment: arfff, sorry to come back . . . in the email fill, the result appear on submit if the user put anything without the @. Do you know how to fix this ? the message by ajax saying it's missing the @ from the form appear so it doesnt send the email, but it does show the result  . .

Comment: Ok I will check it out

Comment: the fiddle is outdated so i can't update it. To do so, you will use the .indexOf method. I tried to update in my code above.
....uemail.indexOf("@")!=-1....

Comment: thank you so much Don Barry, it works perfectly ! you're amazing !